# How to Pin Most Used Files and Folders on Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I have some files on my drive. I want to access to my .md files and some specific folder one click. I wanna pin them to my Dock. What is the best way to access that files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to drag the file or folder to your dock and access it there.  Are you not able to do that?

Comment: I can to do that. But I drag folder all files appear when I click folder. I wanna put files from different folders.

Comment: You can drag individual files onto the dock, too.  That's the only way that I'm aware to do what you want.  You can search the Mac App Store for an app (maybe like HyperDock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Finder, you should be able to click and drag folders into the Dock. Another option is, within Finder, any folders in the sidebar under "Favorites" (where you usually see Documents, Pictures, etc.), you can right-click and select "Add to Dock." This will add it to your Dock in the lower right portion near Downloads and Applications.

Additionally, if you want to create a "general use" folder comprised of documents/files from several folders, you can do the following:

1. Create an empty folder.
2. In the Finder, locate the document you want access to.
3. Right click the document and select "Make Alias."
4. Drag and drop the Alias to the empty folder.
5. Add the folder to the dock.

The Alias should provide a dynamic link to the original file.

Comment: Thank you for your information, please read my comment above.

Comment: I think I was typing when that posted. Sorry about that. I also see the clarification. I'll think on it.

Comment: Could you create a folder of the things you want added (from a variety of folders), then "Create Alias" for the specific documents you want contained in that folder? As I understand, that provides a dynamic link to the original file.

Comment: You understand right, how can I create Alias for specific documents.

Comment: Create the empty folder. Go to a document, right click, "Create Alias," drag Alias into empty folder, Add Folder to Dock. See if that works!

Comment: Oops: It's "Make Alias."